# Using getchar() function

Tags: c++, getchar

I used `getchar()` to stop the while string. My problem is that it does stop the while string if I type one or two characters, if the user input is more the two characters nothing happens.

here is the code:

```
printf("enter srting\n");

while ((tmp=getchar()) !='\n') { \\here is my problem

    count_letters++;
        /* COUNTING WORD THAT START WITH LETTES L,A,C,H */

    while (count_letters%3==0) {
        switch (tmp) {
            case 'A': count_a++;
                break;
            case 'C': count_c++;
                break;
            case 'H': count_h++;
                break;
            case 'L': count_l++;
            default:
                break;
        }
    } /* end of count letters while  */

    n1=n2;
    n2=n3;
    n3=tmp;

    if (n1=='H' && n2=='Y' && n3=='A') {
        count_hya++;
    }



    } /* end of getchar while */
printf("\n");

printf("%d", count_letters);
```

Comment: `while (count_letters%3 == 0)` never ends when `count_letters == 3`.  Cause you didn't update `count_letters` in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

1. I believe it's your code :
   "while (count_letters%3==0))"
   is something wrong!
2. because when you type more than three letters,your variable "count_letters" will add to 3 due to the code:"count_letters++;".
3. May be you could change the "while" to "if" and see if it's working correctly~

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem:

```
while (count_letters%3==0) {
        switch (tmp) {
            case 'A': count_a++;
                break;
            case 'C': count_c++;
                break;
            case 'H': count_h++;
                break;
            case 'L': count_l++;
            default:
                break;
        }
}
```

when your the third character is read, your program enters a infinite loop because of (count_letters%3==0)

I can't understand the purpose of your code.
I suggest using gets() and string manipulation functions because you are processing an entire line. (see string.h)

getchar() is also less efficient compared with gets() + for-loop

Comment: +1 for diagnosis: -1 because of your '`gets()` + for-loop' comment. If the `gets()` in C++ is similar to the `gets()` in C — no bounds on the input, in particular — then you need to go wash your mouth out with soapy water.  Never, ever use the C-style `gets()` function.  Assume it will blow your program sky high. Remember, it was one of the attack vectors for the first Internet worm (Google search term 'morris internet worm'), and it hasn't changed since then. Is there an alternative [`gets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=gets) in C++?